# flexmojo support in maven 3.2.5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-flex, maven-plugin

I am using maven 3.0.5 and i am trying to upgrade it to maven 3.2.5. everything goes fine other than 
flexmojos.

when i build using maven 3.0.5 - the application builds fine whereas the 3.2.5 verison gives me the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-RC2:copy-flex-resources
```

(default) on project ngi-web: Execution default of goal 
org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-RC2:copy-flex-resources failed: 
An API incompatibility was encountered while executing 
org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-RC2:copy-flex-resources: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession.getRepositorySession()Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession;

to resolve this, i updated the flexmojo version to 6.0.0 but still i get error as below

```
[ERROR] Plugin net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-maven-plugin:6.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-maven-plugin:jar:6.0.0: Could not find artifact com.adobe.flex:framework:pom:4.6.0.23201 in all-repos (http://repo.cdiapps.com/repo) -> [Help 1]
```

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

does flexmojo 4.0-RC2 works only with maven 3.0.5?  can someone help me on this?

here is the flexmojo configuration in pom.xml file:

```
  <flexVersion>4.5.1.21328</flexVersion>
    <flexUnitVersion>4.0-rc-1</flexUnitVersion>
    <flexMojosVersion>4.0-RC2</flexMojosVersion>
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>${flexVersion}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex.compiler</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asdoc</artifactId>
                    <version>${flexVersion}</version>
                    <classifier>template</classifier>
                    <type>zip</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <version>${flexMojosVersion}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-flex-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/static</webappDirectory>
                <storepass/>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got today the same error with Maven 3.2.3 and flexmojos 7.0.1.

I found a workaround here: http://mantis.jspresso.org/view.php?id=1186
i.e to replace  flexmojos-maven-plugin:copy-flex-resources' by maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies.

Comment: Ok.. will try this one and keep you posted.

Comment: I had a workaround for this already. when we upgrade the maven, the application specific dependencies that are configured in the pom.xml should be officially released. If the dependencies are alpha or beta version, then the higher version of maven might not work.  This is what happened in my code also. The Flexmojo was configured as 4.0.Beta and it was supported in MAven3.0.5. But failed in maven 3.2.5. when i modified the flexmojo to 3.8 which is the official release, it built fine in 3.2.5.

Comment: @Suresh: "flexmojo to 3.8". 

Are you talking about an old velo's release? The last stable release is the 7th one (https://flexmojos.atlassian.net/wiki/display/FLEXMOJOS/Versions)